# Angular import of component overwrites boot component?

Tags: javascript, angular, import, module

this is my first question here, so please forgive me for not describing my problem well enough. I'm just desperate because I have no clue whats happening here...

I'm working in an angular project and want to reuse a component from a different module. But the moment I import the component, angular decides to use that as a boot component, so when I navigate to the given page, it just shows the imported component and not my original page (in which I want to just insert the imported component).

*Abstract*:
Module A: declares component a and b and exports only b

Module B: declares c and imports module A

-> When I navigate to Module B it shows the component A.a without even launching component B.c
-> intention: I want to use component A.b inside component B.c and just reference it by its selector

My project:
component b (the one I want to reuse) is called "Welcome-Card"

***Module A***

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { LoginPage } from './login.page';
import { WelcomeCard } from "./welcome-card.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [LoginPage, WelcomeCard],
  exports: [WelcomeCard]
})
export class LoginPageModule {}
```

***Module B***

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { SettingsPage } from './settings.page';
import { LoginPageModule } from "../login/login.module";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SettingsPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    LoginPageModule
  ],
  declarations: [SettingsPage],

})
export class SettingsPageModule {}
```

***Module for routing***

```
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  },
  { 
    path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' 
  },
  { path: 'settings', loadChildren: './settings/settings.module#SettingsPageModule' }

];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

***Module B > Component c > html***

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Settings</ion-title>

    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-button (click)="back()">
        <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>

  </ion-toolbar>
  <ion-progress-bar *ngIf="loading" type="indeterminate"></ion-progress-bar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content>

  <welcome-card></welcome-card>
</ion-content>
```

***Module B > Component c > ts***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
import { ApiService } from "../api.service";
import { CommonService } from "../common.service";

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-settings',
  templateUrl: './settings.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./settings.page.scss'],
})
export class SettingsPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private location: Location,
    private api: ApiService,
    private functions: CommonService,
  ) { 
    console.log("contructor")
  }

  loading = false;

  auth = firebase.auth();


  ngOnInit() {
  }



  back(){
    this.location.back();
  }


}
```

***My Project (if you want some files that might be important, don't hesitate)***

```
app
├── api.service.spec.ts
├── api.service.ts
├── app-routing.module.ts
├── app.component.html
├── app.component.scss
├── app.component.spec.ts
├── app.component.ts
├── app.module.ts
├── calendar.service.spec.ts
├── calendar.service.ts
├── common.scss
├── common.service.spec.ts
├── common.service.ts
├── create-challenge
│   ├── create-challenge.module.ts
│   ├── create-challenge.page.html
│   ├── create-challenge.page.scss
│   ├── create-challenge.page.spec.ts
│   └── create-challenge.page.ts
├── current
│   ├── set-success-month
│   │   ├── set-success-month.component.html
│   │   ├── set-success-month.component.scss
│   │   ├── set-success-month.component.spec.ts
│   │   └── set-success-month.component.ts
│   ├── tab2.module.ts
│   ├── tab2.page.html
│   ├── tab2.page.scss
│   ├── tab2.page.spec.ts
│   └── tab2.page.ts
├── current-unset
│   ├── current-unset.module.ts
│   ├── current-unset.page.html
│   ├── current-unset.page.scss
│   ├── current-unset.page.spec.ts
│   └── current-unset.page.ts
├── login
│   ├── login.module.ts
│   ├── login.page.html
│   ├── login.page.scss
│   ├── login.page.spec.ts
│   ├── login.page.ts
│   ├── welcome-card.component.html
│   └── welcome-card.component.ts
├── next
│   ├── tab3.module.ts
│   ├── tab3.page.html
│   ├── tab3.page.scss
│   ├── tab3.page.spec.ts
│   └── tab3.page.ts
├── previous
│   ├── tab1.module.ts
│   ├── tab1.page.html
│   ├── tab1.page.scss
│   ├── tab1.page.spec.ts
│   └── tab1.page.ts
├── settings
│   ├── settings.module.ts
│   ├── settings.page.html
│   ├── settings.page.scss
│   ├── settings.page.spec.ts
│   └── settings.page.ts
├── tabs
│   ├── tabs-routing.module.ts
│   ├── tabs.module.ts
│   ├── tabs.page.html
│   ├── tabs.page.scss
│   ├── tabs.page.spec.ts
│   └── tabs.page.ts
└── types.ts
```

Comment: Pls also include code of the Module B component c html template

Comment: @IhorBodnarchuk, done. Isn't all that interesting though (as far as I can tell). The constructor in the ts file doesn't even get called.

Comment: is there any route that renders WelcomeCard component directly i.e { path: /welcome-card, component: WelcomeCard } ?

Comment: @IhorBodnarchuk, no, there is no route which points to WelcomeCard

Comment: And I am sorry, I had a minor mistake in my described behaviour: When requesting B.c, it shows Component A.a (Login) and not A.b (WelcomeCard). I corrected the question